# Prove $n^2 + n!$ is or is not $\Theta (n^n)$

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics, computer-science

I'm having trouble proving that $n^2 + n!$ is not $\Theta(n^n)$. So far I was able to prove $O(n^n)$ by realizing that $n^2 \leq n^n$ and $n! \leq n^n$, and therefore their sum is less than or equal to $2n^n$. Based on graphs, I think that is is not $\Omega(n^n)$ but I'm not sure how to go about formally proving that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: One way or the other you'll need to understand that $\frac{n^n}{n!}$ behaves like $e^n$, i.e. it blows up. This can be done directly or by quoting Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any complicated formula, as this is straightforward: $$\frac{n^2+n!}{n^n} \le n^{2-n} + \frac{1}{n},$$ which will converge to zero.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why $\frac{n!}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Sorry I mean $n^n$

Comment: @jeanluc sorry for late reply. $\frac{n!}{n^n} = \frac{1}{n}* \frac{2*3*...*n}{n^{n-1}} < \frac{1}{n}$.